# How to create users in on-boarding or checkout process

Tags: mdriven

I have 3 different use case were i want to create a sysusers, in same model:

- in on-boarding process of my customers to the platform my customers
- co-workers register to be users on their organization from email
- invite my customers customers register a account in the checkout
  process.

And I want them to enter their new password i the process.  How do I solve this best?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version the returnUrl is kept even when the user goes through register and that solves the issue. Thanks MDriven for absolutely terrific support!

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is possible to go this route I would suggest that you flip it the other way around. Ask the user to create an account. Once they have an account you promote that account to being coworker and/or customer by setting some state on the already existing sysuser.

... Have a UserInvite object - email the link to a page where the invite is accepted - in the accept page show user link to register or login if they have not done that.
Once you have a CurrentUser and  UserInviteObject in scope you can tie it all together and be done think.

Comment: I did like this:
- Add class UserInvite with ref to Person
- Add Singleton OneUserInviteSession with ref to UserInvite
- Add userinvite object to a Person 
- Send Link to Person
- Add VM that look up the  userinvite object and set userinvite ref to the oneUserInviteSesssion from the link and show link to /account/register
- Add dispatch on index that check if current user dont have ref to person and the OneUserInviteSession singleton have ref to a userinvite object.

Problem is that  UserInvite ref to  OneUserInviteSession is null.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Think you lost me but: When the person switches from not being logged in to becoming logged in he gets a new context - so any transient values you have set will be lost.

Comment: Then I dont understand how to connect the newly created sysuser with the pre created person object after the invited user done the registration.

Comment: Let the Invite view have a button "accept" and have the AcceptInviteView be accessible to LoggedIn users only (by accessgroup) - the user creates account or log in - and is returned to AcceptInviteView - tie the user to the invite object in an action in the AcceptInviteView (or similair - the trick is to only rely on stuff in url and not in context)

Comment: It don't work because when user click Register the returnURL (  http://localhost:8182/Account/Login?returnURL=Turnkey%2fAngularApp%23%2fUserRegistration%2f55!1612) will truncated (http://localhost:8182/Account/Register) and after registration the user end up on the index page instead.

Comment: Ok - so maybe the issue is: When redirected to login and user chose "register" - then the returnUrl is not kept from initial target

Comment: Yes, can this be fixed?